# Importing Wavefront .obj

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to use this example https://github.com/ldo/ObjViewer_Android to import Wavefront .obj file for a game that I'm developing. The problem is that the example is not working for me.

When I compile it in Eclipse, it asks me to remove few @Override methods, and when I run the app on my phone, I get a force close window. There are many files, with very long codes, so it would be a real chalenge to fix the error.

Maybe anyone can tell me what exact files do I need to get the vertices and the textures, and how I can use them. Or are there perhaps better examples?

Comment: If you have much experience with OpenGL and VBO's, you might find that a sample isn't really necessary. The OBJ format is a bit sloppy, but it's pretty straightforward. When I wrote my OBJ importer, I dove in head first with nothing but the spec and a teapot. I suggest, in any case, that you not get hung up on code that's not compiling.

Comment: @stephelton Yeah, i realized that the best choise is to develope the importer all by myself... Parhaps you could drop a link to a good article about importing it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/dataformats/mtl/ http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/obj/obj.html This is all stuff I found on google within a minute or two.

Answer (score 0):

Obj is not the best way to import because you have to convert stuff. Use collada or x3d instead. No conversion will be necessary.